# QT Designer how to assign 2 hotkeys to a QPushButton

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-designer, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I created a simple GUI and assigned "Enter" to QPushButton ("Begin"). This is the line for it:

```
self.Begin.setShortcut(_translate("Form", "Enter"))
```

Evrything works perfectly, BUT how to assign 2 variants of hotkey for the same button? I want the button to react to 2 hotkeys: Enter and Return (Usual "Big Enter" and "Small Enter" on the NumPad)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Probably the simplest is to use [`QShortcut`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html):

```
QShortcut(Qt.Key_Enter, self.Begin, self.handleBegin)
QShortcut(Qt.Key_Return, self.Begin, self.handleBegin)
```

To get the button animation behaviour, try this instead:

```
QShortcut(Qt.Key_Enter, self.Begin, self.Begin.animateClick)
QShortcut(Qt.Key_Return, self.Begin, self.Begin.animateClick)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the QKeySequence class, you could use the QShortcut one: you create two QShortcut triggered when each enter key is pressed; then, you link each `activated` signal of these objects with the `click` slot of your QPushButton:

```
# This one is for the big key
# Creation of the QShortcut, big_enter_seq is an intermediate
big_enter_seq = QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Return)
big_enter = QShortcurt(big_enter_seq, self.Begin)
# Linking
big_enter.activated.connect(self.Begin.click)
big_enter.activatedAmbiguously.connect(self.Begin.click)

# This one is for the keypad key
small_enter_seq = QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Enter)
small_enter = QShortcut(small_enter_seq, self.Begin)
small_enter.activated.connect(self.Begin.click)
small_enter.activatedAmbiguously.connect(self.Begin.click)
```

Notice the `activatedAmbiguously` signal: I send you to the [Qt5 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#activatedAmbiguously) to understand. In theory, this code should work, accordingly to the Qt5 documentation, but on my computer (Fedora 21 with Gnome 3.14.0) the numpad key isn't recognize... The problem lays in `Qt.Key_Enter` which, according to [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum), should refer to the good key... Tell me if it works on your computer!

Comment: Thank you, I'll use the next answer, since it is simplier, but yours was very interesting to read and learn. I don't understand 1 thing: why do we need to create big_enter_seq = QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Return) if we don't use big_enter_seq - anywhere else in the code. May be that' why it doesn't work in your case. Your second line probably should be like this: big_enter = QShortcur(big_enter_seq, self.Begin)

Comment: Yes, all my apologies, I made a mistake, but now I've fixed it! And on your computer, does the Qt.Key_Return work, with the numpad enter?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work. I get a mistake:     big_enter_seq = QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Return)
NameError: name 'Qt' is not defined         (I'm using Qt 5.4)

Comment: You must write `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt` in the beginning of your code ! And does the solution of ekhumoro work ?

Comment: Thank you. 1) After adding from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt  and correcting  of а misspelling (QShortcurt). Your solution works very fine (both Enter and Return). (But there is no button animation as in Ekhumoro answer). 2) Yes, solution of Ekhumoro works fine, but I had to correct to QtWidgets.QShortcut instead of his QtGui.QShortcut - may be because I'm using QT 5 and he (probably) uses Qt 4.  3) I'm grateful to you both for your time and helping. @ekhumoro

Comment: Very strange, none of these solutions seems to work on my computer... Maybe an issue with pyqt! What is your OS? Glad to help you!

Comment: I have Windows 7 Ultimate (32bit and 64bit). PyQt and Qt 5.4 Python 3.4 And why doesn't it work for you? What errors do you get? (By the way: this site proposes me: "  
Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?") - What does it mean? Will messages disappear here if I move them to chat?

Comment: Ok thanks! I don't know why... I've just checked with the C++ equivalent code, and also, it works with Key_Return but not with Key_Enter. Sadly, I don't get any error, even in C++. Our row of comments is certainly too long, we should create another thread to discuss this problem! I don't know, I've never done this